# AngularJS $http request authorization header changing token

Tags: angularjs

I have this $http call after a user has logged in that get's the users' details. When the user logs in I store the token in **user.token** which looks like this:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.erNou7AjihJrp2glS89zNYYFc65mREscGwl45wVUSYA

I then take this token and pass it to an **$http** call like this:

```
$http.get('api/users', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token }, params: { username: model.userName } });
```

But in fiddler if I examine this call, it changes my token. The request in fiddler looks like this:

> Authorization: Bearer cF9xV4hw3psCq2of-wRDn-cRE_IifwzCYyoS-c5Njdk4dGu7EGGQ8Bl_XOr8uEGMAFkxR0paqfCI4Aq17VWP6BDxMZN2Nkk7WIfPLVrilKkMybmGxbOqAKqwl3F1qnEvtlvdgQtdpAqgR6-s1oFU0QemRVaQiyOPbmJwEyfh5mYrNVLuZniPPCvpZvOKKBSpinpCY-vNINI3SYvbZyVpRza18aFJfXy-JgUSN3YZBmg1T4JFjMucCueqAWlulGaDGRc8hAXp7RYnxeUtDO7yOhPzQehjVVxl59Lz461DpsXcZjuEILhlFXbyC4yn24DHIFfLs0_x9DCZwodXaaAwoCmRI_vx8yLpjfoPcmnOR_20lLlWp0pOODOqoKSRxZldnRZO8pbilo_AcYHSCQlyeMPOevvO1bP8yggGdCe_LVQiTNJgzhMccKRcziZqZjPCMw0Kz_OLkR5w2ayS5JTdfA

which is not the token that I passed. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You might have a module included in angular that implements an HTTP Interceptor that injects an auth header.

Comment: What are you using to store the token? We need to see a little more code here.

Comment: Kevin, that is exactly it. I was getting an old token from the cookies which was overwriting what I set in my login function. I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin rightly said, I was setting it on my **http interceptor**. It looked like this:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$location', function ($rootScope, $q, $location) {

    // Function to handle a request
    var request = function (config) {

        // Get the current user
        var user = $rootScope.user;

        // Get the current headers or an empty object
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        // If we have a user
        if (user && user.token) {

            // Then set the authorization header
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + user.token;
        }

        // Return our config
        return config;
    };

    // Function to handle errors
    var responseError = function (rejection) {

        // If we have unauthorized access
        if (rejection.status === 401) {

            // Redirect to our login page
            $location.path('/account/login');
        }

        // Return our rejected promise
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };

    return {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

to fix the issue I just simply put an if statement checking to see if the **Authorization** header had already been set like this:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$location', function ($rootScope, $q, $location) {

    // Function to handle a request
    var request = function (config) {

        // Get the current user
        var user = $rootScope.user;

        // Get the current headers or an empty object
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        // If we have a user
        if (user && user.token) {

            // If we don't already have the authorization header set
            if (!config.headers.Authorization) {

                // Then set the authorization header
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + user.token;
            }
        }

        // Return our config
        return config;
    };

    // Function to handle errors
    var responseError = function (rejection) {

        // If we have unauthorized access
        if (rejection.status === 401) {

            // Redirect to our login page
            $location.path('/account/login');
        }

        // Return our rejected promise
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };

    return {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

simples :)